# Can't add a field to a model in Symfony, bin/console crashes

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sylius, symfony-3.2

I'm working with Sylius framework. I'm following the [guide to customize models](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.3/customization/model.html).

I am trying to add a field `notice` to a model `Taxon` which is already overridden in my project. For that, I added the field description to `Taxon.orm.yml` of the model:

```
MyProject\Bundle\ShopBundle\Entity\Taxon:
    type: entity
    table: sylius_taxon

    # {Relationships code...}

    fields:
        # {Some existing fields...}

        notice:
            type: text
            nullable: true
```

I also added a field, a getter and a setter to the overriding `Taxon` class.

Then I'm trying to run `bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`, but when I run `bin/console` even without any arguments, it crashes with the following exception:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\InvalidFieldNameException]
  An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT s0_.code AS code_0, s0_.tree_left AS tree_left_1, s0_.tree_right AS tree_right_2, s0_.tree_level AS tree_level_3, s0_.position AS position_4, s0_.id AS id_5, s0_
  .created_at AS created_at_6, s0_.updated_at AS updated_at_7, s0_.enabled AS enabled_8, s0_.default_markup AS default_markup_9, s0_.notice AS notice_10, s0_.tree_root AS tree_root_11, s0_.parent_id AS parent_
  id_12 FROM sylius_taxon s0_ WHERE s0_.parent_id IS NULL ORDER BY s0_.tree_left ASC':
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 's0_.notice' in 'field list'`


[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 's0_.notice' in 'field list'`


[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 's0_.notice' in 'field list'
```

If I remove the changes to `Taxon.orm.yml` then `bin/console` works again. What is missing in my changes?

Comment: Looks like this model's repository is injected into one of my custom console commands, and that causes the issue. I'll post the answer when I found which command is that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my bundles' configruation contained that model's repository, that's it. I temporarily deleted the bundle's configuration from `config.yml`, and `bin/console` worked.

Answer (score -1):

When you add new field you should `doctrine:schema:update`

Comment: No, you should use `bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` then `bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

Comment: @Shady this is only if he uses the migrations!!! If he have a manually added table he may not want to use the migrations

Comment: he use Sylius who use Doctrine Migration, so... And he also say in his message he use Doctrine Migration.

Comment: @Shady in Sylius's docs there is written:
`4. Update the database. There are two ways to do it.

via direct database schema update:
$ php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
`